# What is the message of the movie Samsara?

Tags: analysis, samsara

**Summary** of the film [*Samsara* (2001)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsara_(2001_film)):

Tashi (Shawn Ku) began his training as a Buddhist monk at the age of five. Twenty years later, his relationships at the temple became strained after meeting 'Pema'. They marry. Tashi is at odds with his sexuality and an attraction to another lady named 'Sujata', a migrant worker. Racked with guilt over his infidelity, Tashi leaves the farm to return to the monastery.

**Question**

What exactly is the message that the movie 'Samsara' carries? Why does Tashi try to run away from his responsibility for the family? Why is Tashi so confused? In the end, which life does he choose?

Comment: @Vishwa, There might have various articles on this movie. But I want to know the mindset of the Tashi. Why he behaves like that. is he copying `Goutam Buddha`. But `Goutan Buddha's` story is somewhat different. I have seen the movie. But I could not understand what exactly it wants to say. There is great message but whats is that? is that mean - 'There are endless desires in everyone's life and it is difficult to get rid of it.....' What more?

Comment: Posted a [meta request](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4294/please-change-samsara-tag) about the tag

Comment: I didn't see Samsara but I saw Baraka and the Quatsi trilogy and my guess is that the movie -as most Ron Fricke's movies- do not carry any other message than the one you are giving to it. This is the life of a person, with all his doubts and his choices. The camera just happens to be there. There is no intended scenario or message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is the message that the movie 'Samsara' carries?

---

**The message given by this movie is *not good* it is actually misleading people towards sadhus and their lifestyles.**

---

**I bet the director of this film has never seen a real sadhu in his life.**

---

The word **samsara** means "*the cycle of death and rebirth to which life in the material world is bound."*.

> Why does Tashi try to run away from his responsibility for the family?

**Tashi was not an ordinary man** like you and me, he is a man who grew up in a monastery but was unable to see a real monk who could really solve his problem. So he was confused.

**Regret** means desire, which brought him from the monastery to marriage life, and now the same desire takes him to Sujata, even though he loves his wife Pema **(helplessness).**

And in marriage life, the mind isn't free to think about where the problem is coming from.

> Why is Tashi so confused?

> ***In the end, which life does he choose?***

**The motive of the director of this movie is not straight for monks and their lifestyles *that's why I hate the last part of this* movie.**

### Watch these master pieces of film industry

1. **Master of Zen (1994 )** — "One who realize will not speak"
2. **Swami Vivekanand (1998)**
3. **Adi Shankaracharya**
4. **Spring, Summer, Fall, Winter... and Spring**